# Print a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to make sure I copied the 2D array correctly into the 2D vector? But I don't know how can I print this?

Thank you in advance:

```c++
int path1[2][6] = {{6, 0, 1, 5, 6}, {6, 2, 4, 3, 6}};

vector<vector<int>> path2;
vector<int> temp; // For simplicity
for (int x = 0; x <= k; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < customer_inroute[x]; y++)
    {
        temp.push_back(path1[x][y]);
    }
    path2.push_back(temp);
}


vector<vector<int>>::iterator it;

it = path2.begin();
for (it = path2.begin(); it < path2.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << * it;
cout << '\n';
```

Comment: *it would be giving you the inner-vector.  Now loop through that inner vector.  Also, is k defined somewhere (your first for loop)?

Comment: You should clear `temp` after `path2.push_back(temp);`, otherwise it will still contain the elements of the previous iterations when you add the elements of the new ones.

Comment: @maddin45 how can i do it ?

Comment: Just write `temp.clear();` at the end of the outer for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick if you want to use iterators:

```
vector<vector<int>::iterator it;
vector<int>::iterator        it_inner;

for ( it = path2.begin(); it != path2.end; it++ )
{
    for ( it_inner = (*it).begin(); it_inner != (*it).end(); it_inner++ )
    {
        cout << ' ' << *it_inner;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, i have no idea what `customer_inroute[x]` is, but next time include more *real* code with your question. That said, save yourself some typing and do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int path1[2][6]={{6,0,1,5,6},{6,2,4,3,6}};
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > path2;

    for (auto& row : path1)
        path2.emplace_back(std::begin(row), std::end(row));

    // send copy to stdout
    for (auto& row : path2)
    {
        for (auto val : row)
            std::cout << val << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I should note your original `path1` rows are declared to be 6 elements wide, yet you only provide 5 in each initializer list. As a result, the last element is zero filled. The resulting output of the above looks like this, btw:

**Output**

```
6 0 1 5 6 0 
6 2 4 3 6 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. This is one:

```
for (int i=0; i<path2.size(); ++i) {
   for (int j=0; j<path2[i].size(); ++j) {
       cout << path2[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Another, with range-based for (C++ 11):

```
for (const auto& inner : path2) {
    for (auto value : inner) {
        cout << value << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```